# Explode string and output exact 2 elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string

```
$input = 'Hello | world';
```

and I want to explode it to `Hello` and `world`, so

```
$output = explode(' | ', $input);
```

if I have

```
$input = 'Hello | world | third';
```

it returns 3 elements, so I have to slice this array:

```
$output = array_slice(explode(' | ', $input), 0, 2);
```

If

```
$input = 'Hello';
```

then I have to add empty element to have two in the output, so:

```
$output = array_slice(array_merge(explode(' | ', $input), array(null)), 0, 2);
```

Is it possible to make this one-liner simpler ?

Comment: I'd stay with what you already have

Comment: `explode` has the third parameter. Maybe it helps?

Comment: Nope, it will not because with `Hello | world | third` string and third parameter set to `2` it will return `Hello` and `world | third`. For string `Hello` it still returns one element in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = array_slice(explode(" | ", "$input | "), 0, 2);
```

Comment: [If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: You're right! Guess you need the `array_slice` anyway then. Still shorter though;)

Comment: Your code yields `$output[1] = 'world |'` for `$input = 'hello | world'`.

Comment: I used your first revision, now that `array_slice` is involved it does work.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
$first = null;
$second = null;

list($first, $second) = explode('|', $string);
```

**EDIT**

To prevent a notice you could use array_merge:

```
list($first, $second) = array_merge(explode('|', $string), array(null));
```

**OR**

```
list($first, $second) = explode('|', "{$string}|"));
```

Comment: You can also add third parameter to explode, which means limit :) (set it to 3)

Comment: That would raise a `NOTICE` in case `$input = 'Hello'`

Answer (score 0):

As long as the delimited values don't have spaces inside the value, you can rely one the single function call of `sscanf()` with a null coalescing fallback when the string is empty.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/E5hTk))

```
$strings = [
  '',
  '|',
  '||',
  'Hello',
  'Hello |',
  'Hello | World',
  'Hello | World |',
  'Hello | World | You'
];

$result = [];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $result[] = sscanf($string, '%[^| ] | %[^| ]') ?? [null, null];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => NULL,
    1 => NULL,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => NULL,
    1 => NULL,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => NULL,
    1 => NULL,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Hello',
    1 => NULL,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Hello',
    1 => NULL,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Hello',
    1 => 'World',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Hello',
    1 => 'World',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Hello',
    1 => 'World',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of list() and adding the maximum amount of
segments to receive by the explode() function for this, eg:

```
<?php

$in = array(
    "Hello",
    "Hello | world",
    "Hello | My | Lovely | World"
    );

foreach($in as $test){
    list($one,$two) = explode(" | ", $test, 2);
    print_r(array($one, $two));
}
```

If you leave out the third parameter from the explode function you
will only get the first two segments even if there are more - that
would then be similar to your array_slice part.

Comment: It's not working in your example either. `Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => My | Lovely | World
)` is not a desired output